# RSA implementation in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use asymmetric encryption and decryption in dart and went through this documentation :
https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

For encryption and decryption of text they have example :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart';

void main() {
  final publicKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPublicKey>('test/public.pem');
  final privKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPrivateKey>('test/private.pem');

  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final encrypter = Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privKey));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

  print(decrypted); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  print(encrypted.base64); // kO9EbgbrSwiq0EYz0aBdljHSC/rci2854Qa+nugbhKjidlezNplsEqOxR+pr1RtICZGAtv0YGevJBaRaHS17eHuj7GXo1CM3PR6pjGxrorcwR5Q7/bVEePESsimMbhHWF+AkDIX4v0CwKx9lgaTBgC8/yJKiLmQkyDCj64J3JSE=
}
```

At my client, only public key will be available and in the example they want both public and private key to be available for decryption, Is there any way by which my client can have only a public key to decrypt the text created using private key

Comment: _Is there any way by which my client can have only a public key to decrypt the text created using private key._ Encryption with the private key and decryption with the public key is pointless. Anyone could decrypt the ciphertext because the public key is not secret.

Comment: Just to be more specific, public keypair encryption when I'm sending to you is that I use my private key, and then your public key.  You use your private key, and then my public key, which authenticates that it must be from me.